# What is the meaning of an error message "can't find file ***.vrb"? (A fix now known, a full explanation still missing)

Tags: errors, winedt, powerdot

**My system:**

- Windows 10
- WinEdt 10.2.
- MikTeX 2.9.

**The problem:**

I am editing a set of powerdot slides named `Luku16.tex`. All of sudden I started getting these strange error messages when trying to compile within WinEdt (TeX-> DVI -> LaTeX). T

```
 LaTeX Warning: Reference `lastslide' on page 1 undefined on input line 55.

! I can't find file `Luku16.vrb'.
<argument> ...\pd@body \else \input \jobname .vrb 
                                                  \fi \end {pd@minipage}
l.55 \end{slide}
                
Please type another input file name:
```

I am clueless as about the meaning of this. This is a previously uncompiled source file, so LaTeX has not created any auxiliaries yet. What am I supposed to type in here?

I think I managed to create this same behavior once by accidentally creating a new `.tex`-file in a folder that contained residues of another with the same name. This is not the cause here. I renamed the file to exclude this possibility.

**Symptoms:**

- When I look at the listing of this folder, there is a curious file
  with the name `Luku16.synctex(busy)` of filesize 0 bytes.
- The other slide sets in this same folderwork just fine (they do have all the auxiliary files in place already though).

---

Can anyone diagnose this? What should I do to fix this?

---

**More testing:**

The early parts (is it called the preamble or what?)

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{animate}


\begin{document}
```

I am close to a solution in that I have identified a line in the source file causing this. The error message was generated at the end of the title slide. Here's a comparison. When the title slide has the source

```
\begin{slide}{Analyysi II B}
Potenssisarjojen manipulointia ja sovelluksia, Luku 16
\end{slide}
```

The problem does NOT appear. I would prefer to use quotes (because this is not really chapter 16, it's rather "chapter 16" as the book only has 15 chapters. So initially my source looked like

```
\begin{slide}{Analyysi II B}
Potenssisarjojen manipulointia ja sovelluksia, "Luku 16"
\end{slide}
```

And that seems to somehow be too much for LaTeX to handle. Bizarre?

---

Ok, so it is the quotes. I have grown used to using "normal" quotes in place of the ``US style'' quotes. It is bread and butter to fix the resulting spacing errors with `\/`. As the next test I tried the source

```
\begin{slide}{Analyysi II B}
Potenssisarjojen manipulointia ja sovelluksia, "Luku 16"\/
\end{slide}
```

And this also works! No errors. Of course, it is a bit strange to have to add extra whitespace to a place where none is needed, but...

**The main problem is solved.**

I am still curious as to exactly why this happens, so leaving this open in case somebody feels like writing an explanation as an answer :-)

Comment: Can't you reduce your code to a minimal example showing the problem? Hint: it has to do with some slide where you use verbatim material.

Comment: @campa Working on just that. I'm fairly sure you are on to something. I'm about to edit

Comment: Do you use some package which activates the quote?

Comment: @campa It seems to me the removing those quotation marks on my title slide fixed the problem. Why would that be the case? Have I forgotten some basics from the late 80s when I first learned TeX :-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your interest. I added the list of packages in use.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, perhaps your tex system is older. But finnish makes the quote active, so it could lead to errors, better use the correct quotes to quote your text instead of ".

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. It still feels a bit strange, but I have to believe what I am seeing :-)

Comment: I've got the problem too (TeXlive 2017). It seems that `\begin{slide}[method=direct]{title}` fixes it, but I don't really know why... Or without the optional argument but using the correct quotes ``"`..."'``, as Ulrike suggested.

Comment: @campa Thanks once more. For me the problem also disappears, if I add the usual whitespace correction `\/' to the end. May be the quotation mark needs to be the last character??

Comment: sorry but why do you insist of using the wrong input for a quote? The correct input is `` or '' depending which quote you want and not ".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A habit mostly. Also because I had not learned about `\glqq` , `\flq`, `\grqq{}` and friends until [just now](https://technical-tips.com/blog/software/quotation-marks-in-latex--15735). Also, " is always at the same place on my keyboard and I can find it quickly. The others I need to look for and feel kludgier to key in (and may have been relocated from one laptop keyboard to another).  Still, `"...."\/` is faster to type than `\glqq...\grqq{}`.

Comment: well it may be faster, but it gives the wrong output. And I at least would see this in a presentation. And as your language makes " active, curious things can happen. Try e.g. `"abc"-` (and guess first how it look)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As long as I remember to type `\/` to the end I don't see anything funny. I do concede your point that if I mix and try `"abc-"``Luku 16''`, the end result is very surprising! Thanks for bringing this to my notice! You see, the concept of an active character is fuzzy to me. I tried to learn about catcodes and such from the TeXbook back in the early 90s, but never grokked it, and LaTeX does a good job hiding a lot of stuff from me. Most of the time nothing bad has happened!

Comment: Basically I want to use " for the same reason I want to use åäöÅÄÖ in my input files rather than the original Knuth's versions from the time when we were limited to 7-bit ASCII.